# Detecting if a refresh button has been selected while AsyncTasks are still running

Tags: android, synchronization, android-listview, android-asynctask

Iv'e got an Android app that is using a list activity to display a list of items pulled from the internet. I First use an AsyncTask to load the list and that Async task finishes it calls a different async task to start loading the thumbnail pictures that go along with the list items. The problem I am having is that the user has access to a refresh button that they can press at any time and when it is pressed, the whole list of items is delete and the loading starts over. The Async task that loads the thumbnails could potentially still be running if this happens and may try to add a thumbnail to a non existing list item then. Iv'e tried synchronizing on the list, using a Boolean which after researching I realized would not work. I have also tried using a static atomic boolean to check if refresh has been hit to cancel the thumbnail loader. Any ideas?

```
public class LoadItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

private Activity activity;
private static boolean loading = false;
public static final AtomicBoolean refreshing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private static final String TAG = "LoadItems";
private int start;

private List<ListItem> items;

public LoadItems(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    loading = true;
    start = ItemViewer.itemList.size();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    items = WebFunctions.getMoreItems(activity);
    return (items != null);
}


protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
    if (success) {
        for (ListItem item: items) {
            ItemViewer.itemList.add(item);
            Log.d(TAG, "added item " + item.getTitle());
        }
        LoadThumbnails thumbnailLoader = new LoadThumbnails();
        thumbnailLoader.execute(start, ItemViewer.itemList.size());
    }
    loading = false;
}

public void protectedExecute() {
    if (!loading)
        execute();
}

public void refresh() {
    if (!refreshing.getAndSet(true)) {
        WebFunctions.reset();
        ItemViewer.itemList.removeAllItems();
        execute();
    }
}

}



public class LoadThumbnails extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Drawable> {
private int position;
private int end;

@Override
protected Drawable doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    position = params[0];
    end = params[1];
    Drawable thumbnail = null;
    synchronized(ItemViewer.itemList) {
        if (LoadItems.refreshing.get())
            cancel(true);
        String url = ItemViewer.itemList.get(position).getThumbnailUrl();
        if (!url.isEmpty())
            thumbnail = WebFunctions.loadDrawableFromUrl(ItemViewer.activity, url);
    }
    return thumbnail;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Drawable d) {

    synchronized (ItemViewer.itemList) {
        if (LoadItems.refreshing.get())
            cancel(true);
        if (d != null)
            ItemViewer.itemList.setThumbnail(position, d);
        position++;
        if (position < end) {
            LoadThumbnails lt = new LoadThumbnails();
            lt.execute(position, end);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following steps might help:

1. cache the results, whatever you have previously pulled from the net should be saved and quickly restored back when your application is launched. this way you avoid long delays and empty screens on application startup, which, in turn, stops the user from pressing 'reload'
2. make a boolean variable `reload_in_progress`, set it to `true` when you start pulling data from the net, and set it to `false` when all thumbnails are ready. 'reload' click handler should ignore clicks when `reload_in_progress` is `true`.
3. show some king of `progress bar` to the user, so (s)he knows it's already reloading and does not push `reload` again.
4. almost forgot, never update data shown to the user "live", this leads to wonderful situations, when the user clicks on item while it's changing and doing something completely different from what (s)he expected. long updates should keep its data to themselves and quickly swap old data for the new one only when everything is ready.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to solve. Whenever the user hits the refresh button, make sure you call `cancel()` on the last async tasks you have created before you create new tasks. For example,

```
private void onRefreshClick(View v) {
  if(mLastLoadItemTask != null) mLastLoadItemTask.cancel(true);
  if(mLastLoadThumbnailTask != null) mLastLoadThumbnailTask.cancel(true);
  mLastLoadItemTask = new LoadItems(...);
  mLastLoadItemTask.execute();
}
```

Then, in the `onPostExecute` of each of your async tasks, first check to see if they were cancelled by calling `isCancelled()`. If they were cancelled, make sure the `onPostExecute` method does no work by just returning. For example,

```
  protected void onPostExecute(...) {   
         if(isCancelled()) return;
         //Adding items to list 
         //Or start load thumbnail task  
     }
```

As you can see that should prevent any unintentional or stale updates because the `onPostExecute` methods and your `cancel` calls will all happen on the main therad. The last thing I would suggest is to alter your loadThumbs task to be able to stop doing work as soon as possibly by checking isCancelled() whenever it makes sense to do so.